# monotouch - reusable iOS custom view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, subview

OK, so this one is probably a bit challenging, as it is monotouch...

I have a reusable custom toolbar that that I plan to reuse on multiple screens.

I want to create the toolbar in Interface Builder

I want to be able to update labels on the toolbar from ANY view controller. So I might have five different view controllers that all have this toolbar, and can update labels on it.

So my question is:

1. How do I even begin to subclass UIView in MonoTouch? If I create a new "iPhone View", all it gives me is a nib. I have no place to hook up outlets or actions.
2. Given that you are able to tell me how to set up MonoTouch to have C# code files for subclassing UIView so I can handle events and access properties, how do I hook it up to the nib? I see a lot of people saying to use initWithFrame to call loadNibNamed in Objective-C, but this doesn't correctly translate to MonoTouch. How would I do that in MonoTouch?
3. Given that #1 and #2 are fulfilled, how do I load this custom toolbar into any viewcontroller, and add it at specific coordinates on the screen? Doing the initWithFrame CGRect stuff doesn't seem to have a simple path in MonoTouch

If anyone is able to figure this out, you are amazing!!!!

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot of digging, I finally found the answer.

The most informative tutorial was here:

http://sgmunn.com/blog/2012/03/using-loadnib-to-load-a-view/

Essentially, you need to create custom subviews, set them up in the interface builder, then do some simple mapping on the MonoTouch side. But the key point that was throwing me off from the example was this:

**You must, when subclassing UIView, implement the base constructor for IntPtr**

When you do that, everything falls into place. You have your Outlets and Actions hooked up, and can manipulate them at will.

**EDIT: To be more descriptive than just linking...**

> How do I even begin to subclass UIView in MonoTouch? If I create a new
>   "iPhone View", all it gives me is a nib. I have no place to hook up
>   outlets or actions.

Create a new iPhone view, it'll create a nib. Open the nib, set the "custom class" to your custom class. MonoTouch should generate it automatically. If it doesn't, create a new C# class and subclass UIView, but make sure you create the constructor for IntPtr. If you use Storyboards, when you call Storyboard.InstantiateViewController() it'll fill in the IntPtr value for you. Note that if you DO use Storyboard.InstantiateViewController, you need to set the identifier as well to your custom class' name.

Once you create that iPhone view, you should be able to open up "code view" in IB and hook up your outlets and actions.

> Given that you are able to tell me how to set up MonoTouch to have C#
>   code files for subclassing UIView so I can handle events and access
>   properties, how do I hook it up to the nib? I see a lot of people
>   saying to use initWithFrame to call loadNibNamed in Objective-C, but
>   this doesn't correctly translate to MonoTouch. How would I do that in
>   MonoTouch?

There is no initWithFrame: or CGRect in MonoTouch, you use RectangleF. If you load the nib programmatically, you can use the constructor that takes in a RectangleF and use that to set x, y, width, height.

> Given that #1 and #2 are fulfilled, how do I load this custom toolbar
>   into any viewcontroller, and add it at specific coordinates on the
>   screen? Doing the initWithFrame CGRect stuff doesn't seem to have a
>   simple path in MonoTouch

For Storyboards use Storyboard.InstantiateViewController (make sure you set the identifier in IB). For everything else, use:

```
var nibObjects = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("YourViewName", theController, null);
var instantiatedView = (YourClassName)Runtime.GetNSObject(nibObjects.ValueAt(0));
```

as depicted in the above link.

Enjoy! - Allison.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading Nib files from iOS 9 onwards you can use container views and storyboard reference to achieve the same.

[You can check here](https://xamarinexperience.blogspot.com/2019/03/how-to-re-use-views-in-xamarin.html#more)